# QPushButton with border-radius attribe not working

Tags: pyqt5, qt-designer

I have make a button in Qt-Designer with some styling and its working perfectly:

See image. This one is is working perfectly:
[image: See image. This one is is working perfectly]

All CSS attributes work on it,
But when I apply "border-radius" style on it, it is not clickable anymore (means I cannot click it then, and not attach any functionality on it)

This one with "border-radius" is not working.:
[image: This one with "border-radius" is not working.]

Comment: Please share the stylesheet you're using. If you're using more stylesheets, then provide a [mre] for a UI file (remove everything unrelated, just leave the buttons).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.